# file transfer in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Try to explain my problem first.
In my local drive(`C:\temp`) have zip file.I want to transfer this file in the server location.

the problem which i faced, i want to do that without `fileReferenceList.browse();`

```
fileReference = FileReference(fileList[0]);
```

In `fileReference` variable, may be given the file object.

How I can make the process in different way.
Please help me with tutorials or source code.

Comment: Can you explain further, i haven't understand what is your problem ?

Comment: actually i want to transfer a zip file from my pc. this have in folder.the flex load this file from the folder with out file browser.

Comment: You can't do that for security reasons.

Comment: its impossible in flex??

Answer (score 0):

It works only with Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial seems to have source code you can use:  http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/